# How can I make particular cell as border form in excel using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

May i know How can I make  particular cell as border form in excel using java ?
i need only particular cell with table foramat.
Ref: i have enclosed screen shot for more details.

[image]

**My Code:**

```
 try {
        int rowCount = 1;

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("poi-test.xls");

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        HSSFRow row = null;
        HSSFCell cell = null;
        HSSFFont heading_caption_font = null;
        HSSFCellStyle heading_caption_style = null;

        workbook.setSheetName(0,
                              "Ageing Report",
                              HSSFWorkbook.ENCODING_COMPRESSED_UNICODE);

        heading_caption_font = workbook.createFont();
        heading_caption_font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)12);
        heading_caption_font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        heading_caption_font.setFontName("Calibri");

        heading_caption_style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        heading_caption_style.setFont(heading_caption_font);

        row = sheet.createRow(rowCount);
        rowCount += 1;

        cell = row.createCell((short)3);

        cell.setCellValue("Aging Report on UN-acted (DETAILED)");
        cell.setCellStyle(heading_caption_style);
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new Region(1, (short)3, 1, (short)4));

        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i can't able to get reqeried output:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet will do it for you.

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Ageing Report");
Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
Cell cell = row.createCell(3);
cell.setCellValue("Aging Report on UN-acted (DETAILED)");
CellRangeAddress region = new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 3, 4);
RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM, region, sheet, wb);
RegionUtil.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM, region, sheet, wb);
RegionUtil.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM, region, sheet, wb);
RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM, region, sheet, wb);
sheet.addMergedRegion(region);
```